# Which websocket library to use with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, sockjs, engine.io

Currently there is a [plethora of websocket libraries](http://npmjs.org/keyword/websocket) for node.js, the most popular seem to be:

- https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node
- https://github.com/einaros/ws
- https://github.com/LearnBoost/engine.io
- https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io
- https://github.com/sockjs

However I can't find any solid concrete comparisons between any of them...
Apparently Socket.io was awesome, but has become quite dated and has failing builds. Both ws and websocket-node claim they are the fastest. And engine.io seems new, but a lot heavier than the lighter aletarntives.

It would be amazing if we or someone could put together an answer that serves as a guide on which socket library to use and when, as well as a comparison between them.

Comment: If this gets closed, where should a question like this go? As the answer will be incredibly useful... Seems unfortunate that such a prominent question shouldn't reside here.

Comment: Woot woot for community wikis, meaning that despite the question being closed from new answers, we can still improve the community wiki answer below :)

Comment: @balupton can you update the community with your choice and if you are happy with it? is it socket.io?

Comment: @Cgraphics I use Primus with ws these days, as ws is all I needed, if I need something more extreme, I just swap out the undering library and keep the same api thanks to Primus. Works wonders.

Comment: For what it's worth, Socket.IO is solid.  If you need browser compatibility, I recommend it.  If you're looking for something pure websocket, use something else.

Comment: if interested, heres why this got closed: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291052/should-framework-comparison-questions-be-deleted/291129#291129 ( i think)

Answer (score 419, accepted):

Getting the ball rolling with this [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/149978) answer. Feel free to [edit me](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16393046/edit) with your improvements.

- [ws](https://github.com/einaros/ws)
  WebSocket server and client for node.js. One of the fastest libraries if not the fastest one.
- [websocket-node](https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node)
  WebSocket server and client for node.js
- [websocket-driver-node](https://github.com/faye/websocket-driver-node) WebSocket server and client protocol parser node.js - used in faye-websocket-node
- [faye-websocket-node](https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-node) WebSocket server and client for node.js - used in faye and sockjs
- [socket.io](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io)
  WebSocket server and client for node.js + client for browsers + (v0 has newest to oldest fallbacks, v1 of Socket.io uses engine.io) + channels - used in stack.io. Client library tries to reconnect upon disconnection.
- [sockjs](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client)
  WebSocket server and client for node.js and others + client for browsers + newest to oldest fallbacks
- [faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/node.html) WebSocket server and client for node.js and others + client for browsers + fallbacks + support for other server-side languages
- [deepstream.io](https://deepstream.io/) clusterable realtime server that handles WebSockets & TCP connections and provides data-sync, pub/sub and request/response
- [socketcluster](https://github.com/topcloud/socketcluster) WebSocket server cluster which makes use of all CPU cores on your machine. For example, if you were to use an xlarge Amazon EC2 instance with 32 cores, you would be able to handle almost 32 times the traffic on a single instance.
- [primus](https://github.com/primus/primus) Provides a common API for most of the libraries above for easy switching + stability improvements for all of them.

When to use:

- use the basic WebSocket servers when you want to use the native WebSocket implementations on the clientside, beware of the [browser incompatibilities](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client#supported-transports-by-browser-html-served-from-http-or-https)
- use the fallback libraries when you care about browser fallbacks
- use the full featured libraries when you care about channels
- use primus when you have no idea about what to use, are not in the mood for rewriting your application when you need to switch frameworks because of changing project requirements or need additional connection stability.

Where to test:

[Firecamp](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/firecamp/eajaahbjpnhghjcdaclbkeamlkepinbl) is a GUI testing environment for SocketIO, WS and all major real-time technology. Debug the real-time events while you're developing it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Can you explain point 3 in when to use. What are the channels that the point is referring to? I am new to websockets and am trying to understand which one to use in my case.

Comment: What about Autobahn/WAMP?

Comment: Nice list of all available option after death of now.js

Comment: @AkshatJiwanSharma: Channels is the so called 'rooms' each player in a room can exchange messages..

Comment: A small detail for [ws](https://github.com/einaros/ws) is that it needs python. So if you deploy on docker containers or something, you'll need to have python available to use `ws`.

Comment: @EmileCormier WAMP is a subprotocol of WebSocket, not a WS library. op asked specifically about the latter.

Comment: @AkshatJiwanSharma -- me too: "what do you mean by 'channels'"? Maybe it's the **concept** of a channel in the context of a messaging system, as seen on [this JBoss site](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Implementing_Enterprise_Integration_Patterns/files/MsgSys-MsgCh.html) "different message channels provides an elementary way of sorting messages into different message types." I still dunno what it means in context of WebSockets, except for this [websocket-rails doc](https://github.com/websocket-rails/websocket-rails/wiki/Working-with-Channels)

Comment: Deepstream.io server no longer works on Node.js, you now have to run it as a separate service and then add a Deepstream.io client onto Node.js to communicate with the server.

Comment: I've tried `ws`, and it doesn't seem to work very well for streaming.  If it falls behind on messages, it groups them into one and then acts as if it was posted multiple times.  You can write code to figure out when it's doing that and ignore messages, or use something else.

Answer (score 42):

Update: This answer is outdated as newer versions of libraries mentioned are released since then.

> Socket.IO v0.9 is outdated and a bit buggy, and Engine.IO is the
>   interim successor. Socket.IO v1.0 (which will be released soon) will
>   use Engine.IO and be much better than v0.9. I'd recommend you to use
>   Engine.IO until Socket.IO v1.0 is released.
>
> "ws" does not support fallback, so if the client browser does not
>   support websockets, it won't work, unlike Socket.IO and Engine.IO
>   which uses long-polling etc if websockets are not available. However,
>   "ws" seems like the fastest library at the moment.
>
> See my article comparing Socket.IO, Engine.IO and Primus:
>   https://medium.com/p/b63bfca0539

Comment: This reminds me of the usual *Node.js 0.12 is immediate* … they also claim that for months now. So, probably, we'll have to wait and see…

Comment: Do you have any insights/experience with Autobahn/WAMP (http://wamp.ws/)?

Comment: Socket.IO released its v1. Engine.io is not a replacement for it, but used internally by Socket.IO as the transport protocol - it abstracts the actual communication between endpoints (xhr,ws) and has a simple format for packets. Socket.io provides a richer api that 'feels' like an event emitter over the wire.

Answer (score 34):

npm ws was the answer for me. I found it less intrusive and more straight forward. With it was also trivial to mix websockets with rest services. Shared simple code on this post.

```
var WebSocketServer = require("ws").Server;
var http = require("http");
var express = require("express");
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

var app = express();
    app.use(express.static(__dirname+ "/../"));
    app.get('/someGetRequest', function(req, res, next) {
       console.log('receiving get request');
    });
    app.post('/somePostRequest', function(req, res, next) {
       console.log('receiving post request');
    });
    app.listen(80); //port 80 need to run as root

    console.log("app listening on %d ", 80);

var server = http.createServer(app);
    server.listen(port);

console.log("http server listening on %d", port);

var userId;
var wss = new WebSocketServer({server: server});
    wss.on("connection", function (ws) {

    console.info("websocket connection open");

    var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    userId = timestamp;

    ws.send(JSON.stringify({msgType:"onOpenConnection", msg:{connectionId:timestamp}}));


    ws.on("message", function (data, flags) {
        console.log("websocket received a message");
        var clientMsg = data;

        ws.send(JSON.stringify({msg:{connectionId:userId}}));


    });

    ws.on("close", function () {
        console.log("websocket connection close");
    });
});
console.log("websocket server created");
```

Comment: How to get request url in connection metod?

    wss.on("connection", function (ws) {
    // some code console.log(ws.???) get url...
    }

Comment: there is no request url as in ajax requests. The javascript library open a connection to your web-socket server using the an address such 127.0.0.1:8080 or anything.com:7777 , etc... . It is sounds confusing, try to go through some simple tutorial on web-sockets.

Comment: Actually WebSocket endpoints have url too, they start with `ws`, such as `ws://myserver.com`. And yes, they can be configured to be served using 80 and 443 ports too. Using a reverse proxy like nginx, you can route the `WebSocket` protocol urls to another port from the normal HTTP protocols.

Comment: you can simulate routes if you want it.

Comment: using `express-ws` allows to add `ws` routes in express app.

Comment: upvoted! how would you test if this code works or not?