# Node.js Express rendering multiple subsequent views

Tags: node.js, express, view, rendering

I want to do something like:

```
//client -> notifies server that client is connected.

//server -> begins fetching information from DB (series of both async and synchronous requests).

//as sets of data become available on server -> server pushes updates to client via res.render()
```

Basically I have a menu item on the client, and I want to update that menu as the data that the server fetches gets ready. is there any way to do this? I notice I can't do

```
res.render('something');
// again
res.render('somethingElse');
```

Because once render is called, then the response is sent, and render cannot be called again

"Error: Can't set headers after they are sent."

Any suggestions?

Comment: would pushing data from the server to the client be an alternative to your polling solution?

Answer (score 3):

You might benefit from using WebSockets:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

This post has a little bit of info:

[Which websocket library to use with Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392260/which-websocket-library-to-use-with-node-js)

Answer (score 2):

HTTP works via request/response. Typically once the response is sent, the connection is terminated.

To stream data from the server to client, you can use [websockets](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/). There is a very popular node.js module called [socket.io](http://socket.io/), which simplifies using websockets.

Using socket.io, the client code would look like this:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://yourserver.com');
socket.on('data', function (data) {
    updateMenu(data);
});
```

And the server code:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('data', data);
    getMoreDataFromDb(function(data){
        socket.emit('data', data);
    });
    // etc..
});
```

Alternatively, if you want a simpler solution, you can just make multiple small ajax requests to the server, until you get all your data:

```
(function getData(dataId){ 

    $.ajax({
        url:"yourserver.com/getdata",
        data: dataId || {},
        success:function(data){
            updateMenu(data);
            if(data) getData({ lastDataReceived: data.lastId }); // server is still returning data, request more
        }
    });

})();
```