# How to get websocket url path from php or node.js

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

My html code

```
var url='ws://localhost:8000/abc';
  socket=new WebSocket(url);
  socket.onopen=function(){
    log('Success');
  }
```

in php or node.js how to get url path **abc**?

Answer (score 17):

If you're using the [ws library for node](https://github.com/websockets/ws) you can get the URL from the second argument to `ws.connection` which is the request object:

```
const server = new http.createServer()
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server })

wss.on('connection', (ws, req) => {
  console.log(req.url)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a native way to work with websockets in PHP or Node.  You'll need to use a library of some sort.  Fortunately, there are plenty to choose from:

#### [Node.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16393046/1216976)

#### [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12204603/1216976)

Comment: In node.js, wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection from origin ' + request.origin + '.');, but no request.url

Comment: What are you trying to say?