# Sails.js with native WebSockets

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, sails.js

I want to make *public* WebSocket API with [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org). So I'd like to use native WebSockets instead of the built-in socket.io but with Sails.js controllers and models. Is it possible? Maybe I can implement custom transport or something else. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the reason for not using built-in socket.io.??

Comment: API will be public and I don't want to make users use socket.io protocol. They can make their own clients on any platform and there may be no socket.io implementation.

Comment: But if there is no socket.io implementation on the other side how would you be communicating on sockets..??

Comment: Socket.io and WebSocket are different things. For example there is no socket.io implementation in QT but there is WebSocket.

Comment: You can refer to this question.. I hope it will be of great help..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392260/which-websocket-library-to-use-with-node-js

Comment: I read that post. My question is how to connect native WebSocket or [ws](https://github.com/einaros/ws) to sails.js.

Comment: @akshob I wrote custom hook: https://github.com/provectus/sails-userhooks-ws

Comment: @kmakarychev Can you add that as an answer?  It seems like others have the same question and would find it useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I implemented WebSockets support for Sails.js as a custom hook:
https://github.com/provectus/sails-userhooks-ws

Answer (score 1):

Using raw socket.io functionality in a Sails.js controller

https://gist.github.com/mikermcneil/6598661