# HTML5 WebSockets, was the standard changed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, sockets

I'm working with NodeJS and found [this code](https://gist.github.com/bradwright/1021082) that implements kind of native support for sockets since NodeJS doesn't supports sockets by default.

So I used the code to open a server(server is waiting...), now for the client side I used some simple `html` file on my desktop with code [like that](http://plnkr.co/edit/aoJdrjM27wKCWc94Drv7?p=info), well at first glance it fail, but when I debug the code a bit I found out the the NodeJS socket code I found needs `sec-websocket-key1` and `sec-websocket-key2` while I get from the client-side code I implemented([in the plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/aoJdrjM27wKCWc94Drv7?p=info)) only `sec-websocket-key`.

I looked that up and found [that link](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/making-html5-websockets-work.html#fbid=5tnTpJsh9Yr) that saying:

> The first protocol used by HTML5 WebSockets was
>   draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-00 (HyBi 00). All was well until
>   the protocol was upgraded to remedy some security issues. As a result
>   of these changes, the Sec-WebSocket-Key1 and Sec-WebSocket-Key2 fields
>   were added to the client header.

Basically that explains why I get `sec-websocket-key`, I know that article also say that(according to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=websocket)) there only 2 browser supports the latest websockets protocol, I tested with chrome and firefox and both sends the same `sec-websocket-key`...

- What is the *true* protocol I should support(is the right one), the one used `web-socket-key1/2` or just `sec-websocket-key`
- Which browsers supports(if those should be supported) `sec-websocket-key1` and `sec-websocket-key2`?
- Am I doing something entirely wrong with my client-side Web Sockets or the server side?
- Is there a shim to fix something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article is several years old and describes version 6 of the protocol, which was still only a draft is now long obsolete. The current version is 13 and is described in [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455). And this is the version you will find implemented in all current browsers.

Thus it is best to simply ignore the article or only see it in a historical context. For any new implementation please refer to the RFC only and not to any previous drafts.

> I know that article also say that(according to caniuse) there only 2 browser supports the latest websockets protocol,

Looking at [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=websocket) shows that all current browsers support the relevant version of Websockets.

> since NodeJS doesn't supports sockets by default.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392260/which-websocket-library-to-use-with-node-js) from 2013 has an overview of several implementations.  I'm pretty sure that widely used implementations like [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) support the latest version of the protocol.

---

Comment: Steffen, thank you, about the NodeJS implementation, I assume I need new implementation?