# Websocket VS socket.io for a messenging web app

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

i want to developp a messenger web app in realtime with nodejs and i wanted to know what's the best choice between websocket and socket.io for the server and the client side.my concerning is performance, like if i use websocket in both server and client side or socket.io what would be more performant. THX 
THX.

Comment: Already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392260/which-websocket-library-to-use-with-node-js

Answer (score 2):

Don't compare `Websockets` over `socket.io`, `Websocket` is a protocol while `socket.io` is a socket framework (javascript) that uses `Websocket` as one of it's protocol. `Socket.io` (client) will use `Websocket` in communicating whenever it's supported, as a fallback, it will use the old-fashioned `polling` method when `Websocket` is not supported by the clients device.

Comment: You are right and i knew that my concerning is performance, like if i use websocket in both server and client side or socket.io what would be more performant. THX

Comment: As i have said, `websocket` is a protocol, and `socket.io` is a framework that uses `websocket` as one of it's protocol. `socket.io` makes the use of the `websocket` api to connect/send/receive data, `socket.io` make it easier to use the `websocket` api through it's own api.

Comment: Oki thx for your response i will dig to know about performance before making choice

Answer (score 2):

`socket.io` was built on top of `WebSocket`. So there is no chance for it to be any faster than `WebSocket`. I think the role of `socket.io` to `WebSocket` is quite similar to the role of `jQuery` to `Javascript`. `socket.io` has fallback solutions when `WebSocket` is not available. So basically, it supports more browsers. I personally prefer to use `WebSocket` over `socket.io`. It's not because of performance advantage, it's actually about having more controls over the application architecture.

Comment: nice response but look like socket.io give you more flexibility in sending evenement likt with emit you can give a name for an evenement and use that same iname in the server

Comment: @user3741442 It's actually quite the opposite. `socket.io` forces you to use the `event` model for delivering messages. I personally think it's not a good choice of architecture.

Comment: but sometime its better to have that since you dont need to put the type of event in the message that you are sending, let's say you have an chat app you need to send login information through the socket and also new message for exemple if you use websocket you have to put the event type in the data that you are sending

Comment: @Lewis could you elaborate why?